# Calculating the Hessian of a function $f :\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given the gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

We are given a function $f :\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$\nabla{f}(x) =  Px$

where $P \in M_{n \times n}$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

What is the Hessian?

I believe the Hessian is simply $P$, but want to confirm this to be the case.

Comment: Are you assuming that for $x = (x_{1},\ldots, x_{n})$, that $\nabla f(x) = Px$, i.e. that $P$ multiplies the same vector $x$ that is in the argument of $f$?

Comment: @BenCWBrown yes! thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x = (x_{1}, \ldots , x_{n}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and suppose we are given that that $\nabla f(x) = P x$, where $P = (P_{ij})$, $1 \leq i, j \leq n$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. Then we are given that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{k}}(x) = P_{k1}x_{1} + P_{k2} x_{2} + \ldots + P_{kn} x_{n},
$$
for each $1 \leq k \leq n$. We see then that
$$
\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x_{l}\partial x_{k}}(x) = P_{kl}
$$
and so the Hessian is
$$
\text{Hess}f = \bigg( \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x_{i}\partial x_{j}} \bigg) = (P_{ji}) = P^{T},
$$
the transpose of the original matrix $P$. Please let me know if anything seems off, as this is my first time seeing this question.

Comment: This seems right to me!

Comment: Something further I should have added is that the Hessian matrix is symmetric, due to the fact that you can swap the order of the derivatives over. So it seems that $P = P^{T}$ too like your first guess!